# VBA: Before Save Event - Suspend Running Until User Confirms Save As

Tags: vba

I only want my code to run if the workbook is going to be saved. At present, if Save As is selected, the code will run as soon as the user attempts to browse for a file/location. The problem is they can still cancel the save.

Alternatively, I want to be able to run some other code if the user decides to cancel the save. (I don't think the Cancel Boolean in the Before Save event can be used because once the user selects browse, it is assumed the file is being saved)

Maybe the Before Save event cannot be used in this instance but I want to avoid disabling/replacing the Save As functionality if possible.

Comment: Please see the help article about [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your intent is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle this using the After Save event - I didn't realise that this could be used if the file wasn't actually saved.